# Error on instalation of maven 3.3.1 on Windows 8.1

Tags: java, apache, maven, path, windows-8.1

I'm having a problem to complete the instalation of maven 3.3.1 (I don't find the version 3.2.2 to make a download).

The maven folder is located on this program files

> C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.1

In my path, I have this variable created

> M2_HOME - C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.1\apache-maven\src

And my path:

> PATH - C:\Ruby22-x64\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;

(Have a lot of things in my path, I know :( )

But, when I execute the command "mvn -version" the following message is displayed on console:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

I really don't know how to fix it, someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've downloaded the src zip file and you want the bin zip file. Change that, change your M2_HOME to the new path and it will probably work.